# If $p$ prime prove that there exists a permutation $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_p$ such that ...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ prime prove that there exists a permutation $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_p$ of the numbers $1,2, \ldots p$ such that $a_1, a_1a_2, \ldots ,a_1a_2 \ldots a_p$ are all different modulo $p$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I tried to show that it is always possible to find an $a_i$ so that $a_1a_2\ldots a_i$ is different modulo $p$ to all the previous ones. I couldn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for $1 < h, k < p$, the following are all equivalent
 $$
\begin{cases}h = k,\\
hk - h = hk - k,\\
h (k-1) = k (h - 1),\\
h(h-1)^{-1} = k (k-1)^{-1},
\end{cases}$$ where inverses are meant modulo $p$

So we can get (all congruences modulo $p$)
$$
\begin{cases}
a_{1} \equiv 1\\
a_{1} a_{2} \equiv 2\\
a_{1} a_{2} a_{3} \equiv 3\\
\dots\\
a_{1} \cdots a_{k} \equiv k\\
\dots\\
a_{1} \cdots a_{p} \equiv p \equiv 0. 
\end{cases}
$$
by choosing $a_{p} = p$, and then $a_{1} = 1$, and
$$
a_{k} = k (k-1)^{-1}
$$
for $1 < k < p$, where once more the inverse is modulo $p$. By the argument above, the $a_{k}$ are distinct (modulo $p$).

For instance for $p = 5$ you will have $$\begin{cases}
a_{1} = 1,\\ a_{2} = 2,\\ a_{3} = 3 \cdot 2^{-1} \equiv 3 \cdot 3 \equiv 4,\\ a_{4} = 4 \cdot 3^{-1} \equiv 4 \cdot 2 \equiv 3,\\a_{5} = 5.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: A very nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!